# Change Spring boot folder structure for source code and resources

Tags: java, spring, maven

How can I change the path where spring boot is looking for the source code and resources.

I want to move from src/main to src/server/main.

In pom I put:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
            <directory>src/server/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
</build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <mainClass>ema.Application</mainClass> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Error:

> Could not find or load main class ema.Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample build section of a POM that can be used to configure the directories.

```
Check line:  <sourceDirectory>src/server/main</sourceDirectory> 

Check line:   <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
```

Below Sample:

```
<build>
<directory>target</directory>
<outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
<finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
<testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
<sourceDirectory>src/server/main</sourceDirectory>
<scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
</build>
```

Comment: <sourceDirectory>src/server/java</sourceDirectory>
 worked adding this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding directory and source directory to my build fixed the issue;

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <sourceDirectory>opc-ua/src/main</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>opc-ua/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```